# C# User control containing child

Tags: c#, user-controls, children

I created a user control that inherits from `Panel`. The goal is to have a collection of collapsible panels.

[Here is how my user control looks like (no comment on ugly it's :P)](http://hpics.li/c732ad3)
I'm using a main class for the control, another one for the collection (using `CollectionBase`) and a 3rd one, which is item.

My problem is when I add an item, I need the main control to get added another panel. Currently the drawing looks fine, but I'm not getting the expected result.

I'm not sure I clearly expose my problem. Let's say in Visual Studio your are putting Panel1 on Form1, and Panel2 + Panel 3 in Panel 1

The `Form1.Designer.cs` will contain :

```
    Form1.Controls.Add(Panel1);
    Panel1.Controls.Add(Panel2); 
    Panel1.Controls.Add(Panel3);
```

This is what I'll willing to do. I tried to create an event `OnItemAdded` and subscribe to it in order to add the panel but it was not working like a charm, plus it was trigger at any compilation, each time the collection was getting populated while it needs to be done once only.

I'm sorry for my bad english, if I need to clarify something, do not hesitate to tell me. I'm not sure some part of code is need, but if you want, just ask !

Thank you for you hints in advance !

Hi terrybozzio and thank you for answering.

Here is important parts of code.
First class, the main

```
    [Designer(typeof(CollapsiblePanelDesigner))]
    [Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ParentControlDesigner, System.Design", typeof(IDesigner))] 
    public partial class CollapsiblePanel : Panel
    {
        private CollapsiblePanelItemCollection _items = null;

        [Browsable(true)]
        [Editor(typeof(CollapsiblePanelItemCollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]

        public CollapsiblePanelItemCollection Items
        {
            get { return _items; }
        }

        public CollapsiblePanel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
            _items = new CollapsiblePanelItemCollection(this);
        }
```

}

The second class, that inherits CollectionBase is as follow :

```
    public class CollapsiblePanelItemCollection : CollectionBase
    {
        private CollapsiblePanel _owner = null;

        public int IndexOf(CollapsiblePanelItem item)
        {
            return InnerList.IndexOf(item);
        }

        public CollapsiblePanelItem this[int index]
        {
            get { return (CollapsiblePanelItem)InnerList[index]; }
        }

        public CollapsiblePanelItemCollection(CollapsiblePanel owner)
        {
            _owner = owner;
        }

        public void Add(CollapsiblePanelItem item) { }

        public bool Remove(CollapsiblePanelItem item) { }
```

}

```
    public class CollapsiblePanelItemCollectionEditor : CollectionEditor
    {

        private Type[] _types;

        public CollapsiblePanelItemCollectionEditor(Type type) : base(type)
        {
            _types = new Type[] { typeof(CollapsiblePanelItem) };
        }

        protected override Type[] CreateNewItemTypes()
        {
            return _types;
        }
    }
```

The third class, item of the collection  :

```
    [DefaultProperty("Text")]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(CollapsiblePanelItemConverter))]
    public class CollapsiblePanelItem
    {
        private bool _isCollapsed = false;
        private string _text = "Text"; 
        private int _index = -1;
        private Panel _panel = new Panel();

        // simplified properties of course
        [DefaultValue(false)]
        public bool IsCollapsed { { get ; set; } }

        [DefaultValue(typeof(string), "Text")]
        public string Text { { get ; set; } }

        [Browsable(false)]
        public int Index { { get ; set; } }

        public Panel Panel { { get ; set; } }

        public CollapsiblePanelItem() { }

        public CollapsiblePanelItem(string Text, int ContainerSize, Image Image, bool IsCollapsed)
        {
            _text = Text;
            _containerHeight = ContainerHeight;
            _headerImage = Image;
            _isCollapsed = IsCollapsed;
        }
    }

    public class CollapsiblePanelItemConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
    {

        public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
        {
            return (destinationType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor)) ? true : base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
        }

        public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
        {
            if (destinationType == typeof(InstanceDescriptor))
            {
                if (value is CollapsiblePanelItem)
                {
                    CollapsiblePanelItem objValue = (CollapsiblePanelItem)value;
                    Type[] types = new Type[3];
                    object[] values = new object[3];
                    types[0] = typeof(Panel);
                    values[0] = objValue.Panel;
                    types[1] = typeof(string);
                    values[1] = objValue.Text;
                    types[2] = typeof(int);
                    values[2] = objValue.Index;
                    return new InstanceDescriptor(typeof(CollapsiblePanelItem).GetConstructor(types), values, true);
                }
            }

            return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
        }
    }
```

Of course, when you will read CollapsiblePanelItem class, you'll understand I dont know what I'm doing with my Panel... ;)

Comment: what is the "not expected result"?

Comment: Let's say i've myCollapsiblePanel. When I add an item on VS editor, I dont manage to get in myCollapsiblePanel.Designer.cs myCollapsiblePanel.Controls.Add(panel1)

Comment: it sounds like you need at least [DesignerSerializationVisibility( 
    DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content )] since its a collection,and create a class that will be your "item" class and get a typeconverter in that class so your in your control class you have a property of that "item" class with the designerserialization attribute,and add that to your control(your collection will be of type "item").

Comment: I do have the [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)] on the collection but I have no TypeConverter, I should google this up, never heard about it

Comment: Finished implementing the TypeConverter part but it's still not working, i'm getting more and more confused..

Comment: it is best for you to show the code for others also to best understand,having said that,you must create a class deriving from the typeconverter with the canconvertTo convertTo and canconvertfrom and convertfrom overrides then create another class that represent your item in the collection and apply the attribute in that class like for example [TypeConverter(typeof(MyClassConverter))].

Comment: Thanks you for helping me out, I edited my message and posted some part of code of classes.

Comment: ahhh just glared at your code for a bit try deriving your CollapsiblePanelItem from control.

Comment: the problem is still here. It won't add a panel to CollapsiblePanel when I add an item in the VS editor